# Update the existing D3 graph when clicking on ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js, updates

Update D3 graph on click
I am trying to update my graph when the users click on a button, instead of creating a new graph every time. 
Currently, I have an ajax function to get data from the database. such as:

```
 $("#things").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: some url,
        success: function(data) {
            graph(data);
        }
    })
});
```

If the users click on another element on #things, I want the change reflected on existing graph.
Here is my graph function

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.x);})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d.y);})
    .exit().remove()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I can remove svg element form d3 to clear the graph.

```
d3.select("svg").remove();
```

or

```
svg.selectAll("*").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

This guy does a pretty good job of explaining it:
http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8

Try saving the graph and it's data into an object that you can use for the update.

Make your graph function return an object with all of the properties needed for the update.

Create a few functions:

```
// creates a graph from scratch
//@param {array} graph_data
//@return {object} graph 
function graph(graph_data, graph_object){}

// updates the data in a graph and then re-renders it
//@param {array} grap_data
//@param {object} graph_object
function updateGraph (graph_data, graph_object){}
```

Comment: the example is when the user click update on html. But I want to know how to do it from jquery and ajax.